# sql connection on c# smartdevice application

Tags: c#, sql-server, pocketpc, sqlconnection, smartphone

I'm trying do build an application using the pocket pc emulator...
My goal is to connect to a sqlserver express db placed onto another pc
note that in a simple desktop program everything works fine, but in the smartphone program, when this code is run:

```
SqlConnection DatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data source=SERVER\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword");
DatabaseConnection.Open();
```

and when the Open is called, this is the error message:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(String host, SqlInternalConnection connHandler, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor(SqlConnection connection, Hashtable connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

where is the possible error?
the connection string into a desktop app works, the "\SERVER" pc is found by the smartphone simulator...

any ideas?

Comment: the error message is wrote above... sqlexception at....

Comment: Where is the error *message*?. You just posted the error stack.